# Minimum time taken by train to reach its station

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A train starts from station A and reaches station B. It first accelerates at a rate € and then moves with constant velocity and then retards at a rate ¥.But suppose we are to calculate the minimum time the train takes to reach station B, we will assume that train first accelerates and then retards,it does not move with constant velocity in its motion, then how can we calculate the minimum time it takes to reach station B.

This problem becomes very simplier on a v-t graph, but i would like to know the mathematical solution of this using the concept of maxima and minima.

Comment: Calculate the time taken for the whole journey then take the first derivative and equate it to 0

Comment: Unless I miss understood the problem, isn't the first one trivial and demand infinite acceleration until its speed hits $ c $, constant velocity, then infinite acceleration to a stop? Similar for the second. Just accelerate linearly to $ c $ in the middle and slow down?

Comment: The distance between two stops A and B should be known and finite. Infinite acceleration is beyond classical mechanics

Comment: Yeah the distance is finite between the two stations. the total time should be vel/€ +vel/¥. Then take the first derivative of what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if I get something wrong...
You are going to accelerate in the first part of the track (with constant acceleration, let's say, $a_1$) and then you are going to decelerate in the second part of the track (with constant acceleration $a_2$, negative), and ther's no speed limit, so you never travel at constant speed.
Am I right?
 As I see, in this problem there is nothing to optimize. All you need is to find at what time $t$ you have to start decelerating. There is no need to optimize because $v_i=0$, $v_f=0$, and $d_{traveled} = L$
If I'm right, In the first part:

$v_1=a_1 t_1$

$d_1=a_1 {t_1^2 \over 2}$

In the second part of the track:

$v_f=a_2t_2+v_i$ or $0=a_2t_2 + a_1t_1$ where $t_2={-a_1 \over a_2} t_1$ and $a_2 < 0$ and $t_1 + t_2$ is the total time of the travel.

So $L = a_1 {t_1^2 \over 2} + a_2{t_2^2 \over 2} + a_1t_1t_2$

Substituting $t_2$ in the las equation we obtain:

$L = a_1{t_1^2 \over 2} + {a_2 \over 2}({-a_1 t_1 \over a_2})^2 + a_1 t_1({-a_1 t_1 \over a_2})$

Simplifying

$L = ({a_1 \over 2} - {a_1^2 \over {2 a_2}}) t_1^2$

and you obtain

$t_1 = \sqrt{{2L \over a_1}{1 \over {1-{a_1 \over a_2}}}} = \sqrt{{2L}{a_2 \over a_1}{1 \over {a_2 - a_1}}}$

 This is the moment where you need to stop accelerating and start to decelerate.

It's very important to keep in mind that $a_2 < 0$ in the last equation.

This way, the total time of the travel is $t_1 + t_2 = \sqrt{{2L \over a_1}{1 \over {1-{a_1 \over a_2}}}} + {-a_1 \over a_2} \sqrt{{2L \over a_1}{1 \over {1-{a_1 \over a_2}}}} = \sqrt{{2L \over a_1}{1 \over {1-{a_1 \over a_2}}}}({1 - {a_1 \over a_2}}) = \sqrt{2L({{1 \over a_1}-{1 \over a_2}})}$

Comment: There should not be a negative sign in your result at the last

Comment: @MohammadAbid As I wrote since the beginning, $a_2 < 0$.
If your book says that $a_2 > 0$, but retards with $-a_2$, is the same thing.

Comment: It does not comment about the negative sign.it just says it retards with a2

Comment: @MohammadAbid Do your algebra, dude! What happens if $a_1 = a_2$? You get that $t = 0$, an aberration! So $a_1$ and $a_2$ works fine with $a_1 > 0$ (an acceleration) and $a_2 < 0$ (a decceleration) with the _negative sign_. Now, change the sign to positive as you want, is ok to $a_2 < 0$ does that make sense? C'mon man, show some effort! You will find that the sign I used is ok if $a_2 < 0$, but if you want to use the _plus sign_ then $a_2$ *must* be a positive value.

Comment: I am sorry i had not checked your solution fully i just gazed at that answer that is why i thought u might have had made a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: Also i have approved your answer.but i am still finding a calculus based solution.

Comment: @MohammadAbid You can only find the maxima and minima of a function when you have at least one degree of freedom. I mean, when there is one way or another to get to some result and one is the best (or the worst). In this problem, you have only one solution. Zero degrees of freedom (no free variables). The time of travel is determined by the accelerations and the length of the track (all of that is constant). There's nothing you can derive.